# enforce authentication in downloading artifacts from Artifactory Pro using rest api's

Tags: rest, authentication, artifactory

By default Artifactory allows you to download artifacts without providing any authentication. If i have access to the artifactory url, i can download the artifacts from Artifactory. Is there any way to enforce authentication for downloading feature in Artifactory Pro using rest api's

Answer (score 1):

Disable "Allow anonymous access" in general security configuration. [Here's how](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+Security#ConfiguringSecurity-AllowAnonymousAccess).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there anyway to enforce authentication on a particular directory/repository? Say i have two repositories "Test1" and "Test2", is there anyway to restrict access to Test1 and allow anonymous access on Test2?

Comment: Of course. Keep the "Allow anonymous access" checked, and use [Permission Targets](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Managing+Permissions).